# Filter with two conditions

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have a list like this: [('a','b',13), ('c','b', 2), ('c','d',4)]. And I want to remove the element ('a', 'b', 13), but I can't do it like this:

```
filter (\(a,b,w) -> a /= 'a' && b /= 'b') theList
```

This also removes ('c', 'b', 2). I'm new to haskell and don't really know whats causing this.

Thanks

Comment: Use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Oh, that works. But I thought it would be the other way, since I want both 'a' _and_ 'b' in the same tuple.

Comment: Maybe `(\(a,b,w) -> not (a == 'a' && b == 'b'))` is clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Now, `filter` removes all elements for which the filter function doesn't return `True`. Lets take a look at your filter:

```
(\(a,b,w) -> a /= 'a' && b /= 'b')
```

When does this filter return `True`? It returns only `True` if both `a /= 'a'` and `b /= 'b'` are true:

```
 yourfilter       b == 'b'           b /= 'b'
  a == 'a'         False              False
  a /= 'a'         False              True
```

However, that's not what you meant. You want to remove `('a','b',_)`, so your filter should work like

```
 followingfilter          b == 'b'           b /= 'b'
    a  == 'a'              False              True
    a  /= 'a'              True               True
```

You only want to keep the values where `a /= 'a'` **or** `b /= 'b'`, therefore your logical combinator should be `||`:

```
(\(a, b, _) -> (a /= 'a' || b /= 'b'))
```

However, we can also use [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) in order to write a filter for the left upper corner (`a == 'a' && b == 'b'`) and negate its result with `not`:

```
(\(a, b, _) -> not (a == 'a' && b == 'b'))
```